# How can I create particle-in-a-box diagrams in LaTeX?

Tags: diagrams

Interested in creating particle in box diagrams at various energy levels and dimensions. Does anyone have source code to do so or suggestions of good packages to use?

Comment: Hi Helen  This is purely out of curiosity, because I have not yet written any question in LaTeX, why would a diagram (as a graphic) not do the job? I do appreciate that you have a good reason for asking, it's just in case I need to do myself and I want to use the correct method. Is it because the code can be used in the answer? Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I'll give you a minimum working example (MWE) because the TeX people might think this is a physics problem :).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=0.75in}
\usepackage{nopageno}
%The 0.25 is simply a scale factor to make the levels fit. 
%\n is the level quantum number, \x is a variable whose range is 
%determined by the domain statement. The box width of this example is 2.
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:2]
    \draw(0,5)--(0,0)--(2,0)--(2,5);
    \foreach \n in {1,2,3,4}{
        \draw(0,{0.25*\n*\n})--(2,{0.25*\n*\n});
        \draw plot ({\x},{0.25*\n*\n+sin(\n*\x/2*180)}) ;}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That is nice to try to help the OP.  Ideally, if this is merely an MWE, one would edit the OP's question and add this code to it, since this is not itself an answer.  I'm not sure if your reputation level allows that, however.  Also, if you highlight your multi-line code and click the `{}` icon above it, the code gets indented four spaces and displays as code.  The grave accent delimiters are for inline code.  But maybe this is good enough to be an answer?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes, this was originally asked over in Physics. Thanks for adding the output.  I wasnt' the one who transferred it, and I know there are some differences in how the answer boxes work (Physics has MathJax working). Answers are handled a little differently over there than here. Also, the OP didn't have any code and the question was looking for code. Hence, my answer. Why would one add code to a question when the question originally had no code?

Comment: One can edit questions to clarify them (and that can entail adding code).  Obviously, one should be fully confident that one is not changing the questioner's intent?  When I occasionally do it, I draw a horizontal line and identify myself as adding the following edited content.

Comment: As a user who flagged this for migration from Physics.SE (and as a person who doesn't know any Tikz), I subscribe to the difference pointed out by @BillN, and thank him for the MWE. +1 and I have favorited it for future reference.